# Connecting on-premises Microsoft SQL Server to Dataworks using a secure gateway

Tags: sql-server, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, dataconnect

I am trying to connect to an on-premises SQL Server to DataWorks using a secure gateway. I have already created the Secure Gateway (installed the client on my PC and can connect to it).

When I go to dataworks -> tasks -> Create connection -> Microsoft SQL Server, complete the fields and then click on "create connection", I get the error:

> The connection Connection1 could not be validated due to a failure when using secure gateway to access the system.
>
> Ensure that your secure gateway client is running and configured correctly. Contact your system administrator if necessary.
>
> Validation of the connection properties failed and reported a failure using secure gateway to access the system. CDICO0208E: When trying to access the secure gateway TestSecureGateway(yQJbCeTz3fm_prod_ng) endpoint JDBC_XXX_XXX(yQJbCeTz3fm_b2d), on premise address XXXX:port, got the error: Broken pipe, check the secure gateway endpoint status and configuration.
>
> Additional information:
>   Message ID: CDICO8111E;
>   HTTP status: 400

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It could be the SG client is not properly set up, e.g. wrong port, firewall blocking, ... I have a sample app that walks through the setup. https://github.com/data-henrik/Bluemix-onprem-data

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out. You are right, it was a combination of wrong port, firewall, etc.

Comment: I added that hint on what to check as answer, so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Often, the general setup is done correctly, but above error message is encountered. Some things to check:

- is an Access Control List (ACL) for that port enabled on the client? Else the port is blocked.
- is the firewall on database server blocking access by the SG client?
- is the IP address or hostname, which has been specified in the general gateway setup, visible by the SG client?

The SG client may be installed on a separate machine or on the database server, but still a missing ACL could lead to the error.

I personally ran into all of them when I created tutorials for my blog.